# "Instead of delete trigger" triggers two times

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, triggers, ssms

I am using `MS SQL Server 2016` where I have implemented a `instead of delete` trigger. It looks like this:

```
ALTER TRIGGER MyTrigger ON MyTable INSTEAD OF DELETE AS 
BEGIN
    IF --some condition
    BEGIN
        RAISERROR ('Error msg', 16, 1)
        ROLLBACK TRAN
        RETURN
    END
    DELETE MyTable FROM MyTable JOIN deleted ON MyTable.id = deleted.id
END
```

If I execute a `DELETE` statement on the table 'MyTable' and the condition in the if is not fulfilled the `DELETE` statement is executed after the if-block.  This is absolutely correct. But in the console of SSMS it is written twice that the `DELETE` statement was executed. So the following is written in the console:

```
(1 rows affected)
(1 rows affected)
```

I do not understand why. Why does SSMS indicate twice that a row is affected? I use SSMS version `15.0.18338.0`.

Comment: Seems an interesting way to carry out a delete why not use `delete from MyTable where id in (select id from Deleted)`?

Comment: @DaleK I tried it in that way also. Still get the same result.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because there were 2 sets of data effect, the set outside the `TRIGGER`, and then again inside it, because the initial dataset doesn't perform the DML operation itself. If you don't want to see the latter count, turn `NOCOUNT` to `ON`. This, of course, means that if fewer rows are effected in your `TRIGGER`, you won't know about it in the output from SSMS (but it's just informational anyway).

It is also heavily advised that you don't use `ROLLBACK` inside a `TRIGGER`, handle transactions **outside** the `TRIGGER`, not inside. `RAISERROR` isn't recommend either and you should be using `THROW` for new development work (that's been recommended since 2012!). This results in a `TRIGGER` like below:

```sql
CREATE OR ALTER TRIGGER MyTrigger ON dbo.MyTable INSTEAD OF DELETE AS 
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    IF EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM deleted WHERE SomeVal = 'Nonsense')
        THROW 95302, N'Error Msg', 16; --Use an error number appropriate for you
    ELSE
        DELETE MT FROM dbo.MyTable MT JOIN deleted ON MT.id = deleted.id;
END;
GO
```

Comment: Whats the rationale behind not using `rollback` inside a trigger?

Comment: Because the entire statement is already in an implicit transaction with the statement outside it, @DaleK. Doing something like a `ROLLBACK` actually generates an additional error for scenarios like this, `The transaction ended in the trigger. The batch has been aborted.`, meaning that you would be unable to consume `Error Msg` from outside the trigger. `THROW` the error, and then you can both consume said error *and* `ROLLBACK` the transaction if necessary (`THROW` with a state of `16` would normally result in a rollback implicitly on the outer tranasction).